# Making a child route's model query dependent on parent route - promises?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, promise

I'm new to Ember and getting very stuck! I have a child route that needs to wait for the parent route to return it's record set. The child route then needs to do a findByIds for all the keys returned in the parent route (parent returns many keys). My child route looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params, transition) {

   var allPermissions = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: this.modelFor('permissions') });

   return this.store.findByIds('outlet', allPermissions.map(function(item, index, enumerable){

       console.log('in map');
       return item.get('howya_system_key');

   }));

}
});
```

What I'm trying to do here is get all the parent route records, then return the result of of findByIds on each of the parent id's returned.

When I transition into the route it does not error and there is no output from the console.log. I think my problem is that the new ArrayProxy has not been created by the point that findByIds is executed so allPermissions.map has nothing to iterate over.

I'm guessing that I need to implement this via a Promise though I can't see how I'd do it. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I think I've worked out how to do this but I'm not sure I'm doing it the 'Ember' way. I've added a promise and my route now looks like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params, transition) {

    var _this = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
      resolve( _this.store.findByIds('outlet', _this.store.peekAll('permission').map(function(item, index, enumerable){

            console.log(item.get('howya_system_key'));
            return item.get('howya_system_key');

        })))
    });
  }
});
```

Question is, is there a better way and is 'peekAll' the best thing to be using or am I going to end up looking at all store records for a model, rather than just store records for a model related to a parent route query?

UPDATE

OK, solved this. Can't use relationships as suggested below as the parent keys can point at different tables depending on type.

The solution was to use the promise as defined above, but use:

_this.modelFor('ROUTE_NAME').map

Instead of:

_this.store.peekAll('MODEL_NAME').map

I'll also need to filter the ID's to search for depending on Type and present different types in separate routes - but that's for another day.

Comment: Use relationships http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/models/defining-models/#toc_defining-relationships

Comment: Good point but I can't do this as the parent keys can point to different tables depending on type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the final outcome of this where I was shown how to use the promise correctly, please see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484273/ember-route-promise-is-this-doing-what-i-need)