# Ember Route Promise - Is this doing what I need?

Tags: ember.js, promise

I have a route that returns 3 models. Each model needs to be resolved before the route returns the models. I've attempted this using the following pattern (some code redacted to aid clarity)

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params, transition) {

    var _this = this;

    //Set up a hash to pass to RSVP. Ensures that permissions are returned BEFORE outlet and account query
    var getPermissions = {

        permission : this.store.query('permission',query).then(function(permissions){

            var outlets = _this.store.findByIds('outlet', permissions.map REDACTED);

            var accounts = _this.store.findByIds('account', permissions.map REDACTED);

            var result = {permissions, accounts, outlets};

            return result;

        })


    };          

    return Ember.RSVP.hash(getPermissions); 
 }

});
```

This works in so far that all my models are correctly populated in the store, but I'm having issues with accessing attributes in the accounts and outlets models in my controller, but the UI renders these items without issue.

I'm guessing that this promise is not doing what I want, which is to ensure that ALL models are available before the models are returned.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share code where you have problems? What specific problems you have? What template code that is working is looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works in so far that all my models are correctly populated in the
>   store, but I'm having issues with accessing attributes in the accounts
>   and outlets models in my controller, but the UI renders these items
>   without issue.

You have issues with `accounts` and `outlets`, because `Ember.RSVP.hash` is resolved when `this.store.query('permission', query)` resolves.

Make sure you pass all promises to `Ember.RSVP.hash` after `permissions` is resolved:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model(params, transition) {   

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.store.query('permission', query).then((permissions) => {
                let outlets  = this.store.findByIds('outlet', permissions.map REDACTED),
                    accounts = this.store.findByIds('account', permissions.map REDACTED);

                resolve(Ember.RSVP.hash({
                    outlets:     outlets,
                    accounts:    accounts,
                    permissions: permissions
                }));
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, really useful and much appreciated.

Comment: If you've found solution please choose and accept answer.

Comment: Sorry, being dim here - when I click 'Answer' button I just get the option to add text. How do I indicate that one of the responses is the answer?

Comment: Below arrows to upvote or downvote an answer, under the post score, on the left side of answer there is `tick` button to indicate answer to accept. You click this tick button to mark answer as accepted. It will become green after you do that. You can also undo that action. Visit SO help central and tour for look and guide how to accept answer - http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your `model` promise will resolve to a value like this `{ permissions: Array, accounts: Promise, outlets: Promise }`

You want to eliminate the nested promises and end up with a value like this: `{ permissions: Array, accounts: Array, outlets: Array }`

To do this, move the call to `hash` inside:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params, transition) {

    var _this = this;

    //Set up a hash to pass to RSVP. Ensures that permissions are returned BEFORE outlet and account query
    return this.store.query('permission',query).then(function(permissions){
        var outlets = _this.store.findByIds('outlet', permissions.map REDACTED);
        var accounts = _this.store.findByIds('account', permissions.map REDACTED);
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({permissions, accounts, outlets}); 
    });     

 }

});
```

Equivalently, ES6 syntax:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params, transition) {
    //Set up a hash to pass to RSVP. Ensures that permissions are returned BEFORE outlet and account query
    return this.store.query('permission',query).then(permissions => Ember.RSVP.hash({
        permissions,
        outlets: this.store.findByIds('outlet', permissions.map REDACTED),
        accounts: this.store.findByIds('account', permissions.map REDACTED)
    }));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much (again!). That is very helpful.